# get src atribute in a code like this with jquery

Tags: jquery, src, image

```
<div class="thumb">
    <a class="clip-link" data-id="45778" title="Title" href="http://mysite.com">
        <span class="clip">
            <img src="http://mysite.com/17.jpg" alt="Pic alt"><span                   class="vertical-align"></span>
        </span>

        <span class="overlay"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Well I know how to get attributes from a div, class, etc,, but in this case I want to get the pic src from a grid with the given structure, and don't know how to reach the specific clp span with the cli-link data-id, any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[data-id="45778"] > span.clip > img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = 45778,
   src = $('a.clip-link[data-id="'+ id +'"]').find('img').prop('src');
```

Comment: @Mark Have you put your code in document ready handler? http://jsfiddle.net/BN8y3/

Comment: yup  $(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){